# JS/AJAX: Hide/Show select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The function disables select boxes that do not match with the main category. I have one main category and two subcategories. Is there a way i can hide and show the subcategories select boxes instead of disabling them?

**JS/AJAX**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var formObject = {
    run : function(obj) {

            obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
            var id = obj.attr('id');
            var v = obj.val();
            jQuery.getJSON('update.php', { id : id, value : v }, function(data) {
                if (!data.error) {
                    obj.next('.update').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled');
                } else {
                    obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
                }
            });
        }   
}; 
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$('#subc1').show()` and `$('#subc1').hide()`? You probably still want to disable and/or remove, so the data isn't transparently sent in the request. But you won't see the `select`s if you use `$.hide()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *style='display:none;'* attribute.  Or using JQuery, $("#subc1").show() / $("#subc2").hide().

- Show:  http://api.jquery.com/show/
- Hide:  http://api.jquery.com/hide/